# Query DynamoDB to check if a particular item exists or not

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, dynamodb-queries, amazon-dynamodb

I just started out with Node.js and AWS DynamoDB and I am stuck with a very basic problem. I would like to query my DynamoDB which has a "Users" table with "Username"(PKey) and "JoinedOn" columns. Now I would like to write a Lambda function to check if a particular Username exists or not and return a response on the basis of that. Currently I am using the below code:

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const docClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();

const params = {
  TableName : 'Users',

  Key: {
    Username: 'user1'
  }
}

async function getItem(){
  try {
    const data = await docClient.get(params).promise()
    return data
  } catch (err) {
    return err
  }
}

exports.handler = async (event, context) => {
  try {
    const data = await getItem()
    return { body: JSON.stringify(data) }
  } catch (err) {
    return { error: err }
  }
}
```

I am currently hardcoding the key (Username: 'user1') in my code, but I want to avoid doing that as I want to use the same code to check for different users, whether the Username exists in the "Users" table or not.

I want to use SAM. My event.json should look like below, as I want to check if user1 exists in "Users" or not:

```
{
  "Username": "user1"
}
```

On running "sam local invoke TestFunction -e events/event.json", I should get a response "User exists" or "User does not exist"

I am new to AWS and development. Any help is really appreciated.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

you need to define that username in environment variable section of lambda.
then inside the lambda code you can simply call process.env.username.